# System.Web.Http / located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nuget

I'm not sure why am I getting this error now. I referenced an assembly out of Nuget package that is in turn referenced in packages.config file.

This is how the assembly is referenced in my csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I tried to delete the reference in VS and re-reference it again from packages folder without any luck.

Following article mentiones GAC and appbase, but I'm not sure how to find those paths any why the compiler would even look there if the correct file is referenced in my csproj?

[The located assembly’s manifest definition with name xxx.dll does not match the assembly reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2004/03/25/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-with-name-xxx-dll-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference/)

Comment: Can you share what compile error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

One more place to check was `Web.config`. As soon as version conflict was fixed there everything worked.

3 places to check for reference conflicts are:

```
*.csproj
packages.config
Web.config
```